# Don't display a custom field in a list if the field is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, field, custom-fields

Good morning.
I've set a list of custom field modifying function.php. Everything works but I'd like to hide when a field is empty. I've read a lot of posts about it but I can't get rid of my problem.

Here the php code that I have:

```html
   // Show advanced custom fields in product detail page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "ACF_product_content", 26 );
 

function ACF_product_content(){

 
  if (function_exists('the_field')){
    echo '<b>MATERIA: </b>';
    the_field('materia'); 
echo "<br />";
    echo '<b>FECHA DE EDICIÓN: </b>';
    the_field('fecha_de_edicion');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>LUGAR DE EDICIÓN: </b>';
    the_field('lugar_de_edicion');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>ISBN: </b>';
    the_field('isbn');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>ISBN DIGITAL: </b>';
    the_field('isbn_digital');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>ENCUADERNACIÓN: </b>';
    the_field('encuadernacion');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>INTERIOR: </b>';
    the_field('interior');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>MEDIDAS: </b>';
    the_field('medidas');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>NÚMERO DE PÁGINAS: </b>';
    the_field('numero_de_paginas');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>IDIOMA: </b>';
    the_field('idioma');
echo "<br />";
echo '<b>CÓDIGOS IBIC: </b>';
    the_field('ibic');
  }
  
}
```

Anyone could help me to hide one of this fields if it's empty?
Thank you

Comment: Check if the field is empty with a `if`, hide it by not printing it if the `if` is false. You could probably do this a bit neater with a for-loop and an array or something, but a basic if is a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_field` instead and then use condition to check if the field is not empty and then `echo` the  field.

Example:

```
$materia = get_field('materia');
if($materia) {
    echo '<b>MATERIA: </b>';
    echo $materia;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer is perfect

Comment: @Stefano Good. don't forget to accept the answer. :)